# Looking for a particular example with matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-rank

For given dimensions $r$ and $n$, I want a sequence of sets of matrices, $\{ A_i \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times n} \mid i = 1,\ldots, w \}$,  s.t

- $\frac{1}{w} \sum_{k=1}^w \Vert A_k \Vert $ (the average spectral norm of each set) is a non-decreasing function of $w$
- $\frac{1}{w} \sum_{k=1}^w  A_k  $ (the average matrix of each set) is (nearly) constant with increasing $w$

Can someone show such an example? (or show that this is not possible)

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly "nearly constant" is supposed to mean?

Comment: Technically, any constant sequence of matrices ($A_k = A$ for all $k$) will satisfy your conditions. Is there something you have in mind that this example fails to capture?

Comment: Well, I am looking for ``non-trivial" examples where each set is not made of identical matrices like your above example. You can as well give me examples where the average in the set is some constant matrix for each $w$.

Comment: If the sequence $A_k$ is non-constant, then the sequence of averages will be non-constant (but might converge to $0$, for instance). Would you be interested in a proof of this fact?

Comment: I am happy to see any example you can show me. But I guess I am most interested when the averages are constant = some fixed matrix say M

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_w = \frac{1}{w} \sum_{k=1}^w  A_k$.

Note that the sequence $X_w$ satisfies the relation
$$
X_{w+1} = \frac{1}{w+1}(A_{w+1} + wX_w).
$$
Suppose that $X_w$ is (eventually) constant, i.e. $X_w = X$ for some fixed $X$ and all $w$.  Since $X_w = X_{w+1}$, we can rewrite and solve the above equation as follows:
$$
X_{w} = \frac{1}{w+1}(A_{w+1} + wX_w) \implies\\
(w+1)X_w = A_{w+1} + wX_w \implies\\
A_{w+1} = X_w = X.
$$
In other words: if the sequence $X_w$ is constant, then the sequence $A_k$ must also be constant.

Comment: Given a sequence of real numbers, ${x,y,..}$, consider the sequence of sets of matrices, $\{ I - xI, I + xI \}, \{I - yI, I - xI, I+xI, I+yI\}, ..$. This is a sequence of sets of distinct matrices s.t the set average remains constant at I.

Comment: @gradstudent Your example does not fit the description of "$\frac 12 \sum_{k=1}^w A-k$" is constant with increasing $w$". Assuming this comment reflects what you meant to ask, your question as I now understand it is not whether we can find matrices for which the sequence of averages is constant, but whether we can find matrices for which this sequence has a constant **subsequence**.

Comment: I am not understanding your comment. In the example I constructed the average of every set is a constant = I. So my sequence of sets is a valid example of the criteria that I gave in the second bullet point.

Comment: @gradstudent In your example, what happens with $w = 3$? That is, what is $\frac 13 \sum_{k=1}^3 A_k$? If it is not also equal to $I$, then it is not true that $\frac 1w \sum_{k=1}^w A_k$ is constant over $w$.